# How do I query whether any column in a table contains a certain value without knowing which table I'm querying?

Tags: sqlite, search

I have a bunch of different tables each of which have an ID column and I want to provide a search feature which will search all columns of all tables and return the ID column of a row that contains a matching string. Since I want to do this for all columns of all tables I cant do a `WHERE col1 CONTAINS TEXT_STRING OR col2 ...`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you need to do this, you have a problem with the design. but of course there are many times you have to use what other people put on you!

I would create a view, in the view I would create a union of all possible tables. Later you can just search the view. But you have to build index on that column on all the tables otherwise you will get very bad performance.